# What are the terms for the elements in the Euclidean algorithm $a = qb + r$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, terminology

In a ring $R$ with a Euclidean norm $N$, given $a,b \in R$ with $b\neq 0$, there are elements $q, r$ such that $a = qb + r$.

Is there any special terminology for the elements $a,b,q,r$ in this context? For example, if we write $a = \frac{p}{q}$, then $p$ is the dividend or numerator, and $p$ is the divisor or denominator$.

It seems perhaps $b$ could be called the modulus and another number some word with the "and" suffix. Has any terminology been established?

Comment: The same as the classical terminology: dividend, quotient, divisor, remainder. Note that remainders need not be unique generally.

Comment: Doh! I think I've seen that before, but it didn't come up in my searches. I was hoping for more colorful terminology, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a = qb + r$

- $q$ quotient,
- $b$ divisor,
- $r$ remainder,
- $a$ dividend.